# Box2D ObjectSize/Force

Tags: box2d, processing

It seems when I put a bigger radius for my object, the force I apply on them is less effective. Do box2d takes in count the size of the object for calculating the force ?

Here is my code when I create a circleShape :

```
    this._shape = new CircleShape();
    this._shape.setRadius(this._box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(radius));
    this._fixture = new FixtureDef();
    this._fixture.shape = this.getShape();
    this._fixture.density = 1;
    this._fixture.friction = 0.3f;
    this._fixture.restitution = 0f;
    this._body.createFixture(this._fixture);
```

More big the radius is, less forces are on the object. Can I disable this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**. Box2d dynamically computes the total mass of a body based on its fixtures dimensions and densities: a bigger fixture shape would add more mass to the body, so its resistance to change its velocity would be greater; keep in mind that's how it's supposed to work if you want simulate real physics.

However, if you really want all your bodies have the same mass regardless dimensions and densities, you could try:

- Setting a density proportional to your radius circles (the more radius, the less density), or
- Overriding your bodies mass with `void SetMassData(const b2MassData* data);`

Hope it helps.